# How can I configure MSDTC settings programmaticaly?

Tags: c#, transactionscope, msdtc

I had some errors by using TRANSACTION SCOPE due to wrong settings in MSDTC configurations,
so i found the solution...

go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Component Services >  expand Component Services > expand Computers > expand My Computer > expand Distributed Transaction Coordinator > Right Click in DTC Local > Properties >
go to Security Tab.

Now set the things you need, in my case i checked these:

- Network DTC Access               | --> at Security Setting group
- Allow Remote Clients             | --> at  Client and Administration group
- Allow Inbound                    | --> at Transaction Manager Communication group
- Allow Outbound                   | --> at Transaction Manager Communication group
- No Authentication Required       | --> at Transaction Manager Communication group

I want to do this programmatically using c#.

Do someone know how to figure this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729805/MSDTC-Manager?msg=4765921#xx4765921xx

i just made some changes, cause i dont need full features.

Really works

Answer (score 4):

Those settings are stored in the registry.

You can change them there via code and then restart the MSDTC service with the normal .NET Windows Service control class.

I did not find a more official way to change those settings directly.

The key, where the interesting settings are stored, is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security
```

Note that the service name to use for stopping/starting is not `MSDTC` but rather `Distributed Transaction Coordinator`.